# how to change a variable's value within a while loop in makefile?

Tags: c, linux, variables, makefile

I am writing a simple makefile named **run.mk**, as shown in the following code.

```
a = 0 
b := $(shell echo `expr $(a) + 1`)

app: main.o
    gcc -o app main.o
main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c
test:
    while [ $(a) -lt 10 ];\
    do\
      echo $(a);\
      a:= $(shell echo `expr $(a) + 1`);\
      echo $(a);\
    done
```

when i run this makefile using command **make -f run.mk test**, error comes:  **a not found** and loop runs infinitly i.e value of variable a is not updated at  **a:= $(shell echo `expr $(a) + 1`)** within while loop. However at the beginning, value of variable b is set to 1 via the same code line **$(shell echo `expr $(a) + 1`)**. Someone please tell how to update the value of variable a within the loop.

Thank you.

Comment: With GNU make 4.0 you could use Guile to do complex things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up `make` syntax and shell syntax.  Commands that are in a recipe are run by the shell (after make expands them one time).  The shell is a separate process and anything that happens in the shell is completely invisible to make.  All make sees is the exit code (to know if there was an error or not).  It is not possible for the shell to modify the behavior of make in any way (change variable values, etc.)

So with your rule what make does is first expand the recipe for `test` (by the way, this is a very bad name for a target because `test` is actually a real program already on your system), to get this result:

```
while [ 0 -lt 10 ]; \
do \
    echo 0; \
    a:= 1; \
    echo 0;\
done
```

After that expansion is complete it sends that text to the shell to execute, and obviously that will run forever (as well, note that `a:= 1` is not a valid shell command).

Since you only told us what you tried but didn't tell us what you actually wanted to do in the first place, we can't help you do what you want to do.

If what you want to do is write a recipe that will loop 10 times printing a value, you have to do it entirely using shell syntax, NOT make syntax.  Like this:

```
test:
        a=$(a); \
        while [ $$a -lt 10 ];\
        do\
          echo $$a;\
          a=`expr $$a + 1`;\
          echo $$a;\
        done
```

The `$$` escapes variables from being expanded by make, and results in this shell script being run by the shell:

```
a=0; \
while [ $a -lt 10 ];\
do\
  echo $a;\
  a=`expr $a + 1`;\
  echo $a;\
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing shell script variables and make variables.

The recipe for `test` is a shell script (from `while` to `done`). Make variables, such as `$(a)` are expanded before it starts to execute, so the `while` line is `while [ 0 -lt 10 ]` which is always true.
The assignment `a:=...` doesn't work, because it's makefile syntax, not shell syntax. Even if it did work, it wouldn't affect the `while` line.